# Не могу переопределить метод startElement суперкласса хотя и наследую его. SAX

Tags: java, sax

Не могу переопределить метод `startElement` суперкласса хотя и наследую его. SAX подчеркивает ...

> @Override: method doesn't override or implement a method from a
>   supertype.

```
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;    


public class SAXPars extends DefaultHandler{
    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException { 
        ThisElement = qName;  
        System.out.println("Start El");
    } 
}
```

С другими методами получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сигнатура метода корректная, поэтому проверьте, что вы импортировали нужный класс Attributes. Должен быть `org.xml.sax.Attributes`.